# Trouble building onnxruntime from source - FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, windows, winapi, build, onnxruntime

I am trying to build onnxruntime from source, but I run into the following problem.

After executing

```
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime.git
cd onnxruntime
./build.bat
```

I run into the following error

```
2020-08-31 11:14:05,414 Build [DEBUG] - Defaulting to running update, build [and test for native builds].
2020-08-31 11:14:05,414 Build [INFO] - Build started
2020-08-31 11:14:05,414 Build [DEBUG] - Running subprocess in 'C:\Users\xxx\onnxruntime'
['git', 'submodule', 'sync', '--recursive']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\onnxruntime\\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 1795, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\xxx\onnxruntime\\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 1603, in main
    update_submodules(source_dir)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\onnxruntime\\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 409, in update_submodules
    run_subprocess(["git", "submodule", "sync", "--recursive"], cwd=source_dir)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\onnxruntime\\tools\ci_build\build.py", line 400, in run_subprocess
    completed_process = subprocess.run(
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried being more specific about the visual studio version, though I am not sure if this is the issue. Adding the tag `--msvc 16.7.2` yields the same error. This seems like a rather generic error message, maybe not specific to the onnxruntime build.

Using administrative privileges does not help.

What is the cause of this issue and what do I need to do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `—recursive` to download all the dependent submodules:

```
git clone —recursive https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime.git
```

If you want to build it for visual studio , you should open **"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017"** for visual studio 2017 or **"Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019"** for visual studio 2019.
If you use visual studio 2019 you should add this command to end of your command `--cmake_generator "Visual Studio 16 2019"`, like:

```
cd onnxruntime    
build.bat --cmake_generator "Visual Studio 16 2019"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `—recursive` To download all the dependent submodules. Something like:
`git clone —recursive https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime.git cd onnxruntime ./build.bat`